# Django form conditional required, Error message placement

Tags: python, django, django-forms

What i want is for validation error to be displayed next to the company_name field name. Is this even possible?

in my form.py

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    use_company = cleaned_data.get("use_company")
    company_name = cleaned_data.get("company_name")
    use_acn = cleaned_data.get("use_acn")

if not use_company and not use_acn:
    raise forms.ValidationError('Kindly select either a company name or ACN Option')

if use_company and company_name is '':
    raise forms.ValidationError('Pls select company Name')
```

What are my options?

Currently the error are shown at the top of the page using the following template code.

```
    {% for err in form.non_field_errors %}

      <p class="error">{{ err }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `raise forms.ValidationError({'company_name': 'Pls select company Name'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the add_error method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    use_company = cleaned_data.get("use_company")
    company_name = cleaned_data.get("company_name")
    use_acn = cleaned_data.get("use_acn")

    if not use_company and not use_acn:
      self.add_error('use_company','Kindly select either a company name or ACN Option')

    if use_company and company_name is '':
        self.add_error('company_name', 'Pls select company Name')
```

Then you need display it with the field in the template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: this means i run a loop for every error i want to print?

Comment: In the documentation they iterate over all fields to generate the html for the label, input and errors. You can also do this without a loop if you want to build the form by hand.

Comment: using this {{ form.company_name.errors }} i can access individual error field. Problem solved. Thanks @hendrikschneider you have been a big help